# perl if eq statement no work in array

Tags: perl

I have a string

```
$seq1= 'ATCGATGCAATTCCGGAAAAAATTTTCCCGGGGGGGAAACCCGGGAAATTT'
```

so i want to find the frequence of char from user input in this string.

So i change this string to array

```
$base= <STDIN>;  # you can input A or T or C or G
my @Freq1= split //, $seq1;
```

Then use for loop to calculate the total number of char

```
for(my $i=0;$i<@Freq1;$i++) {
  if($Freq1[$i] eq chomp($base)) {
    print "equals $i\n";
    $numberbase++;
  }
}
```

But the `$Freq1[$i] eq chomp($base)` can't work. I don't know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the total chars removed, so just chomp the input once and compare it directly.

```
chomp($base);
for(my $i=0;$i<@Freq1;$i++)
{
    if($Freq1[$i] eq $base)
    {
        print "equals $i\n";
        $numberbase++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use transliteration for this task, which will likely be faster than looping over every base.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                       

use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq = 'ATCGATGCAATTCCGGAAAAAATTTTCCCGGGGGGGAAACCCGGGAAATTT';
my $count = ($seq =~ tr/Aa//);
print "A is seen $count times.\n";
```

Or, you could just use BioPerl to get sequence stats.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::Tools::SeqStats;

my $seqobj = Bio::PrimarySeq->new( -seq => 'ATCGATGCAATTCCGGAAAAAATTTTCCCGGGGGGGAAACCCGGGAAATTT',
                                   -alphabet => 'dna',
                                   -id => 'test' );

my $seq_stats = Bio::Tools::SeqStats->new( -seq => $seqobj );
my $hash_ref = $seq_stats->count_monomers();

for my $base (sort keys %$hash_ref) {
    print "Number of bases of type ", $base, " = ", $hash_ref->{$base},"\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
Number of bases of type A = 16
Number of bases of type C = 10
Number of bases of type G = 14
Number of bases of type T = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason here not to just display *all* of the counts.

Use a hash to keep counts of all four bases, and display its contents in a loop afterwards.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq1 = 'ATCGATGCAATTCCGGAAAAAATTTTCCCGGGGGGGAAACCCGGGAAATTT';

my %counts;
$counts{$_} += 1 for split //, $seq1;

printf "%s => %d\n", $_, $counts{$_} // 0 for qw/ A C G T /;
```

**output**

```
A => 16
C => 10
G => 14
T => 11
```

Comment: I wonder if the down-voter is brave enough to explain himself? I would be grateful to know of any problems with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know the number of occurrence, you could do:

```
chomp $base;
my $numberbase = ($seq1 =~ s/$base/$base/g);
```

Comment: `my $numberbase = map 1, $seq1 =~ /(\Q$base\E)/g;` it's ugly either way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the occurrence of a substring inside a string, you could use the so-called ["goatse operator"](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse__=%28_%29=) `=()=` (which is just two equal signs with a set of parentheses in the middle)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seq1 = 'ATCGATGCAATTCCGGAAAAAATTTTCCCGGGGGGGAAACCCGGGAAATTT';
chomp(my $base = <>);  # user input
my $count = () = $seq1 =~ /$base/g;
print "$base is seen $count times in the sequence\n";
```

This will output a count of 16 for `A`, for example.

The way this works is that the regex with the `/g` modifier can return either a list or an iterator, depending on the context. We want the list, so we impose a list context, which is what the empty parentheses do. Then the `$count` variable assignment imposes a scalar context on the list, which in this case makes it return a count of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Or for a different (more or less 'ugly') version to count them all:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $seq1 = 'ATCGATGCAATTCCGGAAAAAATTTTCCCGGGGGGGAAACCCGGGAAATTT';

my %u;
$seq1 =~ s/./$u{$&}++;$&/ge;

print Dumper(\%u);
```